# Problema com filtro JSON e Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox, filtro

Estou tentando filtrar um JSON com categoria mas não estou conseguindo.

Tenho 3 checkbox e quando vou selecionando elas deveria filtrar um json conforme selecionada. e quando desmarco uma checkbox deveria filtrar somente as que estão selecionadas. Se nenhuma checkbox estiver selecionada devera retornar vazio `[]`.

E quando seleciono uma checkbox e desmarco ela ele retorna somente `[]`.
Segue o código no [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xrkuoqhq/82/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que é necessário filtrar os trechos que contém o vôo da companhia selecionada, poderia simplificar o filtro para verificar se há vôos nos trechos que estejam selecionados:

```
function filtro(valor, selecionado) {

    json.aPesquisa.forEach(function(item) {

        if (selecionado) {
            item.trecho.forEach(function(trecho) {
                trecho.voo.forEach(function(voo) {
                    if (voo.cia.nm == valor) {
                        categoriaList.push(voo);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })

    $("#resultado").html(JSON.stringify(categoriaList));
}
```

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/xrkuoqhq/84/**

Comment: eparei que seu código quando seleciono o checkbox da tam ele retorna o voo.cia.nm com o nome tam e passaredo. teria como ele retornar somente o da tam se so ela estiver selecionada?

Comment: veja agora por favor @EGDEV

Comment: Funcionou perfeito. Muito Obrigado!!!